# How to reference class from AcceptCallBack method?

Tags: ios, sockets, asynchronous

I have used the AcceptCallBack method found in this [tutorial](http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html), which allows my app to receive files from another computer. When I try to use `self` in the AcceptCallBack method I get the following error "use of undeclared identifier 'self'", I was wondering if there is anyway I can use `self` to call other methods in the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AcceptCallBack` is a C function, and is not part of any class, so there is no `self` pointer.  However, there is a way to get a void* passed to the function, which can be anything you need; you can pass a pointer to your `self` object in this way.

Specifically, the function prototype is:

```
void AcceptCallBack(
CFSocketRef socket,
CFSocketCallBackType type,
CFDataRef address,
const void *data,
void *info)
```

You probably want `info` to point to your object.  To do that, you need to set the info member of `CFSocketContext` to be your `self` pointer:

```
struct CFSocketContext {
CFIndex version;
void *info;
CFAllocatorRetainCallBack retain;
CFAllocatorReleaseCallBack release;
CFAllocatorCopyDescriptionCallBack copyDescription;
};
```

when you set up the callback in `CFSocketCreate`.  Then when `AcceptCallBack` is called, the pointer you want will be passed through.  It is up to you to make sure this pointer is valid; if your `self` is released, then the pointer will be invalid.